# I cannot make my soft keyboard appear on 4.0+ emulatora

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-softkeyboard, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

It was supposed to be easy to make soft keyboard appears on Android 4.0+ emulator. I either add Keyboard parameter in AVD manager and set it to 'no' or manually edit `config.ini` file. I did both, but soft keyboard does not appear when I press into `EditText`. This is how my emulator's config file look like:

```
hw.accelerometer=yes
hw.lcd.density=160
sdcard.size=500M
skin.name=WXGA800
skin.path=platforms/android-15/skins/WXGA800
hw.cpu.arch=x86
hw.keyboard.lid=no
hw.keyboard=no
abi.type=x86
vm.heapSize=48
hw.ramSize=1024
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-15/x86/
```

Anyway, soft keyboard still does not work!

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Does it work if you press CTRL+F11? Also, does it work in an ARM emulator instead of x86?

Comment: @Ari Haven't checked on ARM. It so slow that I cannot test anything. Especially on tablet emulator. Ctrl+F11 (or num 7) does nothing. It only rotates the emulator.